# Why on some Android devices I can't take a picture while recording a video

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, android-camera

Why on some Android devices I can't take a picture while recording a video. If I `unlock()` my camera for video recording and try to take a photo, my `camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);` don't call the `onPictureTaken()` method of my `PictureCallback jpegCallback`.

If I don't start a video record I can take as many photos I want with lock()-ed camera. I have tested this on many devices and this is issue only on some of them.

Taking this thread simple for now. I can post code and test results with devices.